# docker-compose=> sh: 1: ./entrypointsh: not found but entrypoint shows in LS

Tags: docker, docker-compose

So I'm trying to set up a docker-compose file, and do some data initialisation in it. However when I do `docker-compose up` in my terminal (windows one + tried a bash one) I get `sh: 1: ./entrypoint: not found` despite it showing the file when I add `ls` to my command.

```
mssql_1      | data
mssql_1      | entrypoint.sh
mssql_1      | init.sql
mssql_1      | table
```

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  mssqldata:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
  mssql:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    volumes:
      - /var/opt/mssql
      - ./sql:/usr/src/app 
    working_dir: /usr/src/app 
    command: sh -c 'chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh; ./entrypoint.sh & /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr;'
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
      SA_PASSWORD: P@55w0rd
    volumes_from:
      - mssqldata
```

Folder structure:

```
docker-compose.yml
sql/
  data/
  table/
  entrypoint.sh
  init.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this should be happening in your dockerfile instead of in your docker-compose.yml file. Generally the idea behind docker-compose is to get a multi container application running and to get the containers in a multi container application to talk to each other. So for example in your context it would perhaps be to get three containers to communicate with other for a asp.net+ MSSQL + IIS container.

In any case what you are trying to achieve you can do in your dockerfile
I'll try write this dockerfile for you as far as possible. Here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 1433


ADD  entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

# I suggest you add starting : "/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr" to the entrypoint.sh script it would simplify things a bit.

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Here is the docker-compose.yml file that you need:

```
version: '2'
services:
  ms-sql-server-container:
    image: mssql-container:latest
    # This refers to the docker container created by building our dockerfile with:
    # docker build -t mssql-container  .
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=P@55w0rd
    volumes:
      - ./sql:/usr/src/app 
    # I don't really understand the reason for the second volume that you had if you can kindly explain, then I can edit my answer to accomodate the second volume
    # if I think that you need it.
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: I built and tried everything on my side. After building the image with the docker build command I provided, then you can run: `docker-compose up` that should do the trick. I was able to get everything running on my machine without any errors.

Comment: Seems I forgot to copy a bit, I based myself on: https://cardano.github.io/blog/2017/11/15/mssql-docker-container . Still a bit of a docker newbie. Do I just place that dockerfile on the same level as my docker-compose file and run the docker build command first then docker-compose? And sorry for the late reply, was a bit swamped yesterday.

Comment: I tried your setup, but I got: 
Step 5/7 : ADD  entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder052537581/entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory

Is it possible a copy of the sql folder is needed in the Dockerfile?

Comment: Looks like the dockerfile should be:
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest

COPY sql /usr/src/app

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 1433

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "./entrypoint.sh"]

Comment: So already looking a lot better, thank you for the input. One thing I'm still having a bit of an issue with. How do I start the sql server from the dockerfile? If I put it in my entrypoint like: exec /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr it stops as soon as the data import in my entrypoint.sh is done

Comment: Make sure your entrypoint.sh file is in the same directory as your docker-compose.yml file. You can start the server with: ``` $ docker-compose up ``` in the same directory as the docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: the copy bit solves that. the issue I have now is with starting the sql server and keeping it up in a non blocking fashion in my entrypoint.sh in which I do table creation + data import

Comment: @KristofPlennings It would be very kind if you could edit your answer and include the appropriate fix to your problem, so others can benefit.

Comment: @gdyrrahitis sadly I didn't find a proper solution for this. It's been a while but if I recall correctly I switched over to a windows based image and moved some scripts around.